# Processing XMLHttpRequest object with Javascript

Tags: javascript, get

This might be an easy fix for most of you but I can't figure it out.
I am creating a function to call a GET method but I am having problems in processing the response. This is my code:

```
function getAPI(url) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest
  xhttp.open('GET',url)
  xhttp.send()
  return xhttp
}

let xhttp = getAPI('http://127.0.0.1:8000/myapi/')
console.log(xhttp)
console.log(xhttp.response)
```

When I console.log the xhttp I can see the right API response... but when I log the xhttp.response it appears as an empty value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [any tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest).

`XMLHttpRequest` (as with pretty much all external data access in JS) is **asynchronous**.

The event loop **isn't** frozen (completely blocking all JS and UI) until the response comes in.

You need to use an event handler to determine when the data is available.

```
xhttp.addEventListener("load", function () {
    console.log(this.response)
});
```

---

> When I console.log the xhttp I can see the right API response

The developer tools console evaluates object lazily. It doesn't check the value of response until you expand the object (which is after the property has been updated).

---

Note that the modern replacement for `XMLHttpRequest`, [the `fetch` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) is [`Promise` based](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) so supports the more convenient [`async` / `await` syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await).

Comment: So... If I want to save the output in a variable to be used in other functions what approach do you suggest me? Shall I save it in the localStorage?

Comment: Putting it in localStorage makes it available on other pages, but doesn't solve the problem of it taking time to get the data. Use promises.

Comment: Ok. Can you help me out with that because I am newbie.Happy to use "fetch" rather than XMLHttpRequest :D

Comment: I don't have time to write a new tutorial on using promises, I linked to a couple in the answer.